# Python objects variables getting mixed up?

Tags: python, class, object, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to solve a travelling salesman problem using python(3.7). I have defined a Route class for my route objects:

```
class Route:
path = None
distance = None
fitness = None
probability = None

def __init__(self, path=None, distance=None):
    if distance is None:
        distance = 30000
    if path is None:
        path = []
    self.path = path
    self.distance = distance
```

And my genetic algorithm is defined as follows.

```
def ga(initial_pop, distances, n_generations, pop_size, mutation_rate=1.00):
best_for_run = Route()
generation = initial_pop
for i in range(0, n_generations):
    calculate_fitness(generation)
    normalize_fitness(generation)
    mating_pool = create_pool(generation, pop_size / 2)
    new_generation = []
    for j, individual in enumerate(mating_pool):
        if j + 1 == len(mating_pool):
            child1, child2 = crossover.cxPartialyMatched(individual.path, mating_pool[0].path)
        else:
            child1, child2 = crossover.cxPartialyMatched(individual.path, mating_pool[j + 1].path)
        mutate = random.random()
        if mutate < mutation_rate:
            child1 = scramble_list(child1)
        child1_distance = calculate_route_distance(child1, distances)
        child2_distance = calculate_route_distance(child2, distances)
        first_child = Route(child1, child1_distance)
        second_child = Route(child2, child2_distance)
        new_generation.append(first_child)
        new_generation.append(second_child)
    generation = new_generation
    best_routes = get_best_routes(generation)
    for ind in best_routes:
        if ind.distance < best_for_run.distance:
            best_for_run = ind
            print('ind:        ', ind.path, ind.distance)
            print('best_for_run', best_for_run.path, best_for_run.distance)
            print('Calc route distance', calculate_route_distance(ind.path, distances))
            print('----------------------------------------')
return best_for_run
```

As I see it this should return the route object with the shortest distance. But at some point the distance for each object (or path?) is getting mixed up so that if you calculate the returned objects distance it will differ from the one printed.

For example if I run the code like this:

```
distances = get_cities('cities.xlsx')
pop = initial_population(100, distances)
best = ga(pop, distances, 1000, 100, mutation_rate=0.4)
print('Best for run', best.path, best.distance)
```

I get this output:

```
ind:         [3, 11, 13, 2, 8, 1, 15, 10, 0, 7, 6, 4, 5, 14, 9, 12] 4564
best_for_run [3, 11, 13, 2, 8, 1, 15, 10, 0, 7, 6, 4, 5, 14, 9, 12] 4564
Calc route distance 8439
----------------------------------------
ind:         [10, 9, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 11, 15, 13, 0, 5, 14] 4425
best_for_run [10, 9, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 11, 15, 13, 0, 5, 14] 4425
Calc route distance 5811
----------------------------------------
ind:         [2, 5, 3, 7, 12, 14, 9, 10, 13, 15, 11, 1, 0, 4, 6, 8] 4375
best_for_run [2, 5, 3, 7, 12, 14, 9, 10, 13, 15, 11, 1, 0, 4, 6, 8] 4375
Calc route distance 6132
----------------------------------------
ind:         [3, 10, 12, 9, 15, 4, 13, 8, 14, 5, 7, 2, 0, 1, 6, 11] 3941
best_for_run [3, 10, 12, 9, 15, 4, 13, 8, 14, 5, 7, 2, 0, 1, 6, 11] 3941
Calc route distance 6068
----------------------------------------
ind:         [6, 0, 3, 8, 10, 9, 2, 11, 1, 12, 7, 15, 4, 13, 5, 14] 3775
best_for_run [6, 0, 3, 8, 10, 9, 2, 11, 1, 12, 7, 15, 4, 13, 5, 14] 3775
Calc route distance 6586
----------------------------------------
ind:         [2, 9, 8, 7, 4, 14, 11, 12, 10, 13, 15, 6, 5, 1, 0, 3] 3374
best_for_run [2, 9, 8, 7, 4, 14, 11, 12, 10, 13, 15, 6, 5, 1, 0, 3] 3374
Calc route distance 3374
----------------------------------------
Best for run [7, 1, 11, 2, 4, 12, 13, 5, 3, 0, 10, 6, 9, 15, 14, 8] 3374
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe not related, but `path` and `distance` are both class and instance attributes, not the best idea/practice

Comment: Oh you're right I should change that. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it was not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I seem to have found a solution, instead of calculating all the routes distances in the "reproduction loop" I created a method for calculating the distances for an entire generation and use this where I replace the old generation:

```
def calculate_generation_distance(generation, distances):
for individual in generation:
    individual.distance = calculate_route_distance(individual.path, distances)
return generation
```

.

```
generation = calculate_generation_distance(new_generation, distances)
```

Still not sure why things where getting thrown around in the first place. I’m guessing it’s a feature.